# Date Parameters and Values From SSAS Tabular 2016 / SSRS 2016

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, dax

I have a tabular model in SSAS, with a date column as a dimension member - set to date and general in SSAS column properties.

When I use this column to return data in SSRS 2016 - and more importantly - as a parameter, it looks like a string - with no date picker. I also can’t use things like > @date or < @date as a filter.

Have I missed a step to declare the column as a date. I’m used to using this in a standard sql connection which works perfectly - just not in SSAS Tabular / DAX.

Any help appreciated

Thanks,
W

Answer (score 2):

You need to change both the "Data Type" and "Data Format" to date types in your SSAS tabular data model. Please see the image below:

[image]